# Combine ASP.NET Routing and system.webserver > httperrors

Tags: asp.net, iis, routes, http-error, custom-errors

Reading some posts in the internet, seems to be a good solution to handle the 404 errors by system.webServer > httpErrors (IIS).

This is because ASP.NET customErrors doesn't cacth URLs different than .ASPX extensions, so it's not a good real solution.

Using httpErrors, IIS catches all URLs that doesn't exists, and IT works great.

But in my current project i'm using ASP.NET Routing to beautify my URLs. So, you can call, for example: www.mysite.com/mycategory

Then, ASP.NET Routing cacth the request and convert it (internally) to the real URL, for example: www.mysite.com/mypage.aspx?category=mycategory

That works very well, but since the moment I enabled system.webServer > httpErrors in my web.config, IIS is cacthing this kind of requests and blocking it, because the URL doesn't exists (Fisically www.mysite.com/mycategory doesn't exists, obviusly) and my URL Routing has stopped working.

It could be solved somehow?

Many thanks.

EDIT:

Noticed that IIS 7.5 Works good, i mean, is cacthing all inexisting URLs, and respecting the Routing configuration.

My problem, then, is only for IIS 7.0

I will appreciate any help.

Thanks.